# How to use videos in react native snap carousel? Perhaps another better carousel package for react native?

Tags: react-native, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

Is it possible to add Video component into the [react-native-snap-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel)? I want to try to create a carousel similar to Instagram's swipe

I was able to get swiping to work, but when I tried to add the video component from expo, it didn't show up.

```
const _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Video uri={item.uri}/>
          <Text>{index} What are we trying to accomplish here {item.uri}</Text>
          <ComponentVideo uri={item.uri} />
        </View>
      );
}
```

`<ComponentVideo />` is another component I created, works normally. `<Video />` is a component from expo that's inside ComponentVideo. I just brought it out to see if it works.

Thoughts?

Perhaps there's another package I should check out?

Comment: You can't add the video inside react-native-snap-caraousel but you can make your own custom caraousel. In which you can add videos and images.